# Get text aligned at bottom div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Link to project](https://jsfiddle.net/uj7ru281/)

I've have finally managed to get the header layout I want but one thing I can't get done and that is the alignment of the text (h2 and h3) in the left sidebar. I have tried to do it with a fixed proportie but it get side-effects and I think it has something to do with the rotated text.

The main title should be in left bottom, on one line and the date should be on the right of the main title also on one line. Those combined must align at center of the side-main text aligned to the left.

Edit: [Link to layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoLDf.jpg)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper-header {
  display: flex;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #F33C12, #F28BB8);
}

.top-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.side-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  border-right: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) solid;
}

.agenda-text {
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-main {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rataplan Improvisatietheater</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-nav">
    nav
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-header">
    <div class="side-main">
      <h2 class="agenda-text">Main Title Event</h2>
      <h3 class="agenda-text">Event date 1 (month) 2018</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="header-main">
      main
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-content">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit velit, natus dolores, exercitationem debitis praesentium. Ipsam, nesciunt, vero placeat repellendus hic ex, numquam eos iste earum cum dolores omnis maiores.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Hope you can help me out.

Regards,
Jason

Comment: include the html and make this a snippet

Comment: What would you like it to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look super polished as a whole yet, but I believe it does solve your issue with the rotation of the `side-main`.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rataplan Improvisatietheater</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top-nav">
            nav
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-header">
          <div class="side-main-wrapper">

            <div class="side-main">
              <h2 class="agenda-text">Main Title Event</h2>
              <h3 class="agenda-text">Event date 1 (month) 2018</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="header-main">
                main
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-content">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit velit, natus dolores, exercitationem debitis praesentium. Ipsam, nesciunt, vero placeat repellendus hic ex, numquam eos iste earum cum dolores omnis maiores.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper-header{
    display: flex;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #F33C12, #F28BB8);
}
.top-nav{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.side-main-wrapper {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.side-main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 70px;
    width: calc(100vh - 60px);
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(255,255,255,.2) solid;
}
.agenda-text{
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-main{
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Rather than rotating the entries of the flex column, I wrapped the `side-main` in a `side-main-wrapper` and rotated that. Then I just treated the `side-main` as a regular flex column, and it started behaving.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I can work with your edit and it works in the design I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I added `flex: 1;` and some `margin-left` to `.agenda-text` and then opened up the `.side-main` width a bit. Hope this is something like what you are looking for, but just guessing since you didn't specify

*Edit*: Looks wack in preview and fullscreen... but works in the actual edit jsfiddle screen... maybe this is not a good answer

*Edit* Took out flex: 1 and margin-left. I've made it look how you described, but with an issue. I think a big step forward is adding a container around the .agenda-texts and then rotate that instead of the text. The problem with my approach is that the flex positioning is based on the width of the sidebar, before everything gets turned sideways. So with a left bar width like 300px it works but with a smaller width like you are looking for probably not. Can't imagine making this fully responsive without doing the whole thing over

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper-header {
  display: flex;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #F33C12, #F28BB8);
}

.top-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.side-main {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  border-right: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) solid;
}

.side-main-title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.agenda-text {
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-main {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rataplan Improvisatietheater</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-nav">
    nav
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-header">
    <div class="side-main">
      <div class="side-main-title">
        <h2 class="agenda-text">Main Title Event</h2>
        <h3 class="agenda-text">Event date 1 (month) 2018</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-main">
      main
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-content">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit velit, natus dolores, exercitationem debitis praesentium. Ipsam, nesciunt, vero placeat repellendus hic ex, numquam eos iste earum cum dolores omnis maiores.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I've specified what I'm looking for in the main description.

Comment: @Jssonline, just clarify again as it probably means that your description was not good.

Comment: @JGallardo he added something where there was nothing before. But perhaps clarify the horizontal/vertical direction you are talking about, as it is all relative.

Comment: Here is the layout that I'm looking for: [link](https://imgur.com/OvHNoTp). There must be a way that all just fit in nicely without much use of margins. Thank you guys!

Comment: @StefanBob Thanks for your updates. I've tried the option you write about but get the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Np sorry it isn't 100%. I'm sure you'll get a better answer from someone else soon